# asp:Login -- How to trim spaces of UserName before authentication process?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, trim, asp.net-authentication

The `asp:Login` allows the user enter also leading and trailing spaces, and the spaces then are part of the `UserName`. In the leading space case, the problem is discovered soon. However, when only a trailing space is used by the user (accidentally), the authentication against the non-space user-name account is successful. Then...

When using the `Page.User.Identity.Name` is saved by the application and later compared with the same value with accidentally inserted trailing space, it is (surprisingly) not equal :) In other words, the `Page.User.Identity.Name` in one session can differ from `Page.User.Identity.Name` in another session by the same user -- having trailing spaces.

While it is possible to use the `Page.User.Identity.Name.Trim()` every time, it is error prone, and I would like to do the trimming during login.
What is the correct way to trim the login name in `asp:Login` before it is used for authentication? Can the `Login.LoggingIn` event be used for the purpose somehow?

Comment: Use `myString.Trim()` when dealing with user names or email adresses.

Comment: @VDWWD: the application already uses `Page.User.Identity.Name` on about 40 places, and the number will grow. I can use `.Trim()` at all of the places, but it is likely that someone else (not being aware of the problem) will forget to add the `.Trim()`. Because of that I want to solve it from beginning.

Comment: That is why you should (have) use(d) Trim when adding or registering a user. `User.Identity.Name` just holds the username that is retrieved from the database. You could do a search and replace on the database to remove the spaces.

Comment: @VDWWD: I have the asp.net WebForm application, and my experience is different. The standard database with user accounts registers the user using UserName without spaces. The `asp:Login` allows to log in also the same username with trailing spaces (using the same password). The `User.Identity.Name` returns what was typed into the login dialog when the user logs in -- and not the name that was used when the user account was created.

Comment: Login.aspx.cs:
`string username = tbUserName.Text.Trim();`

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved it. Just override `LogginingIn` event and update username as needed.

```
protected void Login1_LoggingIn(object sender, LoginCancelEventArgs e)
  {
        Login1.UserName = Login1.UserName.Trim();
  }
```

Also note the `Page.User.Identity.Name` will maintain the username with same capitalization as user entered it - it can be confusing if you save it in some other paces and it starts from upper case than other day lower case. To solve this I also made read in database and replaced the Username with value form the database, to make sure the capitalization is consistent across user login attempts.